# Get Credential Provider for Authenticated Users

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-plus, amazon-cognito, credential-providers

My android app logins with Google Plus, I am trying to integrate it with Cognito. When I run the app, it gives me Cognito Credential Provider ID, and when I login with Google Plus it gives me Google token. I checked my AWS Cognito, and it shows me this.

```
Unauthenticated connections 3
Google Sign-in 0.
```

But when it signs in properly with Google, and also provides me Google Token, then where I am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:** Here is my code:

[Login with Google Plus](https://github.com/mohit-mittal/New-UniCloud/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/unicloud/mittal/loginWithGooglePlus.java)

[Cognito Sync Client Manager](https://github.com/mohit-mittal/New-UniCloud/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/unicloud/mittal/CognitoSyncClientManager.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you may want to include relevant code from your application to better help others assist you.

Have you followed the guide for [integrating identity providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#integrating-identity-providers)?

It's also important to note that the CredentialsProvider does lazy loading, meaning simply adding the token to the provider does not associate the identity. To ensure the token is actually linked to the identity, you can either:

- Make a call to another service (for instance the SyncManager) that using this provider (*recommended*)
- Explicitly call `refresh` on your CredentialsProvider. (*only recommended for testing purposes*)

**Edit 1**

Did you add the tests I suggested in my original answer? If so, what if any errors did you receive?

You may want to try some of the following steps to verify your configuration:

- Inspect the token via [jwt.io](http://jwt.io). Validate that the azp field of the token matches the value entered into the Cognito console.
- Create an OpenId Connect provider via the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#providers), adding all client ids from the Google console. Use this provider instead of the basic Google+ integration in your Amazon Cognito identity pool.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have followed the guide for integrating identity providers. I also have included a link to my code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @user2798227 You should not put your information in a public repository. Your pool allows unauthenticated access and could be abused.

Comment: I have now edited cognito Identity Pool and changed the unauthenticated role to none, and also unticked the "Enable Unauthenticated users". I left the space blank in the code for Unauth_role_arn like this `private static final String UNAUTH_ROLE_ARN = "";` I tried to run the program again, it runs, gives me credential provider, then I connect with google plus and it gives me google token. Then I checked the Cognito console again. It still says Signin with Google = 0.

Comment: @user2798227 I've updated my answer with additional information.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting my google token in jwt.io. I received some junk values after decoding. But when I tried replacing my token with accesstoken in this link `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken`, in the issued to it gives me my client id. That means my it is a correct token, isn't it?

Comment: @user2798227 No. This means you are using an access token, not the id token. Apologies for not noticing earlier, but your code is not the code included in the [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#integrating-identity-providers). Please use this code or take a look at our [sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo).

Comment: Thanks for replying. If you look at my code, login with Google plus file, and search for this string "doInBackground(Void", you will find that I'm using the same code which is included in the guide.

Comment: @user2798227 Your code is using SCOPE, which is not the correct value to get an id_token. You should change this to mScope. Additionally, you do not appear to be calling refresh or any api calls. As I mentioned in my answer, this will ensure enforce the link on the identity.

Comment: I have tried using mScope, it logins with Google plus, but gives me `GoogleAuthException: Unknown` in the logcat. Can you check if I am initializing mScope correctly? 
I will call refresh once I get this working. Thanks

Comment: @user2798227 mScope contains ":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", you should remove this.

Comment: Just to let you know, The client id which I have entered here was created using the steps given in the [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#set-up-google). 
Now, when I am using mScope, and it looks like this `String mScope="audience:server:client_id:899555500747-q6gfkucloightgtisgspnsnuvhid2hrb.apps.googleusercontent.com";`, It still gives me the same error. `GoogleAuthException: Unknown`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70799/discussion-between-bob-kinney-and-user2798227).